# Hikari pool activeConnections not showing in JMX mbean

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvisualvm

I was monitoring the `spring boot` application through `java Visual Vm`. I want to monitor the connection pooling . HikariCP is the one used for `connection pooling`.  I am not able to see the number of `active connections` in the details. Attached screenshot. Doesn't it exposed by default or should we programatically do it? please advice

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to expose metrics through MBeans setting next property

```
spring.datasource.hikari.registerMbeans=true
```

[image]

Comment: Correct, as per documentation in https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP.